# Can I change the ownership of an Asana API app?

Tags: asana, asana-connect, asana-api

I inadvertently created an app using an old Asana account that I'd now like to deactivate. I'd like to transfer ownership of the app (keeping the same client ID) to my actual active account. Is there a way to do this?

I could create a new app (with a new client ID) on my active account, but I'd then need to ask all my users to re-auth, which I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I work on the Asana platform team.

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to transfer an app's ownership from one Asana account to another.